# Can't connect to Tor Network (Failed to find node for hop #1)

Tags: configuration, bootstrapping

The log is here.

```
8/5/2018 20:57:57 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 20:58:07 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 20:58:07 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 20:58:07 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 20:58:07 PM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 20:58:07 PM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
8/5/2018 20:58:07 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:08 PM.300 [WARN] The connection to the HTTP proxy server at 192.168.1.9:80 just failed. Make sure that the proxy server is up and running. 
8/5/2018 20:58:08 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:09 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:10 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:11 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:12 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:13 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:14 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:15 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:16 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:42 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:43 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:44 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:45 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:46 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:47 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 20:58:55 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 20:58:55 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 20:58:55 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 20:58:55 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
8/5/2018 21:02:10 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 21:02:10 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 21:02:10 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 21:02:10 PM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 21:02:10 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:11 PM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
8/5/2018 21:02:11 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:12 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:13 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:14 PM.700 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:19 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:20 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:21 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:22 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:23 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:24 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:25 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:26 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:27 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:28 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:29 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:30 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:31 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:32 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:33 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:34 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:35 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:36 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:37 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:38 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:39 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:40 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:41 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:42 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:43 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:44 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:45 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:46 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:47 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:48 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:49 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:50 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:51 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:52 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:53 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:54 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:02:55 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:03:21 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:03:22 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:03:23 PM.600 [WARN] Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:194.109.206.212:443): It seems that our clock is ahead by 15 hours, 2 minutes, or that theirs is behind. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
8/5/2018 21:03:23 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (Clock skew 54125 in NETINFO cell from OR; CLOCK_SKEW; count 2; recommendation warn; host 7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 at 194.109.206.212:443) 
8/5/2018 21:03:23 PM.600 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
8/5/2018 21:03:23 PM.600 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
8/5/2018 21:03:23 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 21:03:23 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 21:03:23 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 21:03:23 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
8/5/2018 21:01:57 PM.200 [NOTICE] Your system clock just jumped 122 seconds backward; assuming established circuits no longer work. 
8/5/2018 21:01:59 PM.600 [NOTICE] Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 0:16 hours, with 0 circuits open. I've sent 22 kB and received 602 kB. 
8/5/2018 21:01:59 PM.600 [NOTICE] Average packaged cell fullness: 67.470%. TLS write overhead: 10% 
8/5/2018 21:05:00 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 21:05:00 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 21:05:00 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 21:05:00 PM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 21:05:01 PM.100 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:02 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:03 PM.100 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:04 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:05 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:06 PM.100 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:07 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:08 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:09 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:10 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:11 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:12 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:13 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:14 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:15 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:16 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:17 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:18 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:19 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:20 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:21 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:22 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:23 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:05:24 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:02 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:03 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:04 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:05 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:06 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:33 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:34 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:35 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:36 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:37 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:24:38 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:04 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:05 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:06 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:07 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:08 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:09 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:10 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:11 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:12 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:13 PM.500 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:14 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:15 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:16 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:17 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:18 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:19 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:20 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:21 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:22 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:23 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:24 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:25 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:26 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:27 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:28 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:29 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:30 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:31 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:32 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:33 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:34 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:35 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:36 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:37 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:38 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:39 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:25:40 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:06 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:07 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:08 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:09 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:10 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:11 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:12 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:13 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:14 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:15 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:16 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:17 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:18 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:19 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:20 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:21 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:22 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:23 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:24 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:25 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:26 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:27 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:28 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:29 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:30 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:31 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:32 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:33 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:34 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:35 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:36 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:37 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:38 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:39 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:40 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:41 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:26:42 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:08 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:09 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:10 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:11 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:12 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:13 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:14 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:15 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:16 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:17 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:18 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:19 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:20 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:21 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:22 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:23 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:24 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:25 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:26 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:27 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:28 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:29 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:30 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:31 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:32 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:27:33 PM.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
8/5/2018 21:29:16 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (IOERROR; IOERROR; count 10; recommendation warn; host 175921396C7C426309AB03775A9930B6F611F794 at 178.62.60.37:443) 
8/5/2018 21:29:16 PM.400 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
8/5/2018 21:29:16 PM.400 [WARN]  7 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
8/5/2018 21:29:16 PM.400 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
8/5/2018 21:29:16 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
8/5/2018 21:29:16 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 21:29:16 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/5/2018 21:29:16 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/5/2018 21:29:17 PM.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or not may not work depending on the exact error.

1. Update your countries Exact Time / Time Zone & Location settings.
2. Restart
3. Cool Beans, all should work !

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 checkpoints to fix this:

- Install NTP daemon **and** buy for 20-50 USD a GPS shield with PPS output and USB-SPI or USB-I2C bridge, it will give you a Stratum 0 time grade on your node
- Obtain/install some bridges, install is preferred. You will elaborate them with keys so it will shield you from DPI
- Install the Bind 9 DNS server with root hints only and route it through Tor - so no DNS-trigger will arise for a censorship of your connection